# How to deploy and host vite-ssr-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, vite, server-side-rendering, netlify

I have just created my first vite-ssr-reac-app and im trying to publish it to the web, but i cant find where to host it for free.. I have tried netlify and firebase but it does not seem to work. Do you have any tips to where to host the app?

I tried netlify and firebase, but it did not work. In netlify i got "Page Not Found", and the same for firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your build settings and commands: In your project settings in Netlify or Firebase, you should specify the build command (vite build for a Vite project) and the publish directory (dist in a Vite project). It seems you're already aware of this, but it's worth double-checking. The "Page Not Found" error often occurs when the publish directory is incorrectly set.